# Inserting array containing json objects as rows in postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, jsonb

Just started using PostgreSQL 9.5 and have ran into my first problem with jsonb column. I have been trying to find an answer to this for a while but failing badly. Can someone help?

I have a json array in python containing json objects like this:

```
[{"name":"foo", "age":"18"}, {"name":"bar", "age":"18"}]
```

I'm trying to insert this into a jsonb column like this:

```
COPY person(person_jsonb) FROM '/path/to/my/json/file.json';
```

But only 1 row gets inserted. I hope to have each json object in the array as a new row like this:

```
1. {"name":"foo", "age":"18"}
2. {"name":"bar", "age":"18"}
```

Also tried:

```
INSERT INTO person(person_jsonb)
                VALUES (%s)
                ,(json.dumps(data['person'])
```

Still only one row gets inserted. Can someone please help??

**EDIT: Added python code as requested**

```
import psycopg2, sys, json

con = None
orders_file_path = '/path/to/my/json/person.json'

try:

    with open(orders_file_path) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    con = psycopg2.connect(...)
    cur = con.cursor()
    person = data['person']
    cur.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO orders(orders_jsonb)
                    VALUES (%s)
                """, (json.dumps(person), ))
    con.commit()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        if con:
            con.rollback()

    finally:

        if con:
           con.close()
```

**person.json file:**

```
{"person":[{"name":"foo", "age":"18"}, {"name":"bar", "age":"18"}]}
```

Comment: Show some lines of the file you are copying from. Show the relevant code where the `insert` is tried.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have made some edits to include further details :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the simplest schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test(data jsonb);
```

## Option 1: parse the JSON in Python

You need to insert each row in PostgreSQL apart, you could parse the [JSON on Python side](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and split the upper level array, then use [`cursor.executemany`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) to execute the INSERT with each json data already split:

```
import json
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect('...')

cur = con.cursor()

data = json.loads('[{"name":"foo", "age":"18"}, {"name":"bar", "age":"18"}]')

with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES(%s)', [(json.dumps(d),) for d in data])

con.commit()
con.close()
```

## Option 2: parse the JSON in PostgreSQL

Another option is to push the [JSON processing into PostgreSQL side using `json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect('...')

cur = con.cursor()

data = '[{"name":"foo", "age":"18"}, {"name":"bar", "age":"18"}]'

with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO test(data) SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(%s)', (data,))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: `execute_batch` ([see here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-exec)) will give better performance over `executemany`